# GitLab Custom CI configuration path and merge request

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

For one of our repositories we set "Custom CI configuration path" inside GitLab to a remote gitlab-ci.yml. We want to do this to prevent Developers to change the gitlab-ci.yml file (as protected files are available in EE Premium and up). But except this purpose, the Custom CI configuration path feature should work anyway for Merge Requests.

Being in repo
group1/repo1

we set
.gitlab-ci.yml@group1/repo1-ci

repo1-ci repository exists and ci works correctly when we push to configured branches etc.

For Merge Request functionality GitLab tells us:

Detached merge request pipeline #123 failed for ...

Project `group1/repo1-ci` not found or access denied!

We added the developers to repo1-ci repo as developers, to be able to read the files. It does not help. Anyway the expectation is, that it is not run with user permissions, so it should simply find the gitlab-ci.yml file.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So our expectations were right an it seems that we have to add one important thing into our considerations:

If a user interacts in the GitLab UI with the Merge Request features and you are using "Custom CI configuration path" for your gitlab-ci.yml file, please ensure

- this user needs at least read permissions to that remote file, even if you moved it to another repo on purpose (e.g. use enhanced file protection in PREMIUM/ULTIMATE or push/merge protect the branches for the Developer role)
- the user got this permission change applied in a running session

The last part failed for our users, as it worked one day later. Seems that they just continued working from their open merge request page and GitLab checks the accessibility out of this session (using a cookie, token or something which was not updated with the the access to the remote repo/file).